# Transparent gradient shadow in css all browsers

Tags: css

I want to css code with gradient top transparent color. can you please check below is it correct.?

```
background-color: transparent;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f2f2f2, rgba(242, 242, 242, 0));
bottom: 0;
content: " ";
display: block;
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 8;
```

Comment: That code works just fine, you might want to use a color that shows a bit more though, try #f00 and you'll see it works as is

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use just `background` property for your purpose if i undetstood it correctly.

```
.example {
   background: linear-gradient(to top, #f2f2f2, rgba(242, 242, 242, 0));
}
```

Cause you use second color with `opacity: 0` (last parameter in the `rgba` function) you'll have gradient effect to transparent.

Comment: I like to use [generators like this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to get the code right. This one gives a bunch of prefixes and shows browser compatibility.

Comment: I don't understand why you answered since the given code work as is using `background-image` ?

Comment: @LGSon My advice is based on specification of `background-image` property and `background` property. You would check the info on w3c.

Comment: Since  [_CSS linear-gradient_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) is supported on both properties and W3C states [_gradients can be used in any property that accepts images_](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients) I don't understand what you are talking about

Comment: @LGSon Ok, i was sure on another point of view. So as we can see from candidate we would use `background-image` property to for this function but anyway in my opinion developer should use logical property for proper action. Don't you agree that f.e. `background-clip` property isn't good solution if even this version would work?

Comment: I agree, but not this case, since `background` is a shorthand version for amongst other `background-image`, they are equally logical.

Comment: In my opinion `background-image` more logical for `url` function